# Django: what is the better way to get users info from models in view or template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have few django models and I want display some information the for several users in the template.
Below are the models:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_url = models.URLField(max_length = 200, blank = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

class subscription(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,default=None, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='creator',)
    booster = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,default=None, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='booster')
    sub_value = models.FloatField(blank = True)
    sub_id = models.TextField(blank = True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dateSubscribed = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    dateSubscriptionEnded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    paymentCount = models.FloatField(default= 0)
```

I want to pass few users to template and display how many posts and subscriptions each user has? I am wondering what is the best way to do it? Is better number of posts and subscribers information in the view and just pass those things to template or pass users get that information in the template? Thanks!

Comment: if you want to see it in list view, you can do Post.objects.all().order_by('author')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model => View => Template

Try to parse as much of the information from the model in the view as possible. The reason for this is the pure python in the view runs fast and is nicer to work with the pure python. So when I can I try to break down information in the view into lists of objects. So for your example.

determine what users you want and add them to a list then loop through the list filtering using the username or id.
ex:

Post.objects.filter(author='User')

then create a list of objects with the relevant user, post count, and sub info.
then pass this to the template you can loop through the list using all the relevant data in your objects.

hope that was clear and useful some of that is my own development bias there may be a better way but that's how I have approached a similar issue in the past. good luck!

Comment: Hey, I am having trouble implementing this. I asked another follow up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58894056/django-create-custom-object-list-in-the-view-and-pass-it-to-template-to-loop-o?noredirect=1#comment104053097_58894056). If possible can you answer this? Thanks!