# Django : Create custom object list in the view and pass it to template to loop over

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I want to create a custom object list in the view and pass it to the template. In the template I want to loop over the list and display the information.

My models are

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_url = models.URLField(max_length = 200, blank = True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)

class subscription(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,default=None, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='creator',)
    booster = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser,default=None, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='booster')
    sub_value = models.FloatField(blank = True)
    sub_id = models.TextField(blank = True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dateSubscribed = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    dateSubscriptionEnded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    paymentCount = models.FloatField(default= 0)
```

I want to filter objects from subscription model like below

```
subs = subscription.objects.filter(booster = request.user)
```

Then find creators in the above subs object list and for each creator get the name, numbers Posts, and number of Subscribers. Add this to custom list and pass it to the template to loop over and display the information in the template. Can someone help me how to create this custom list. Thanks!

Comment: If you have the `CustomUser` instance, you can use the reverse relation with, as your related name is: `request.user.creator.all()`, I suggest to use a related name more relevant, like `creator = ......  related_name='created_subscriptions'`

Comment: where is the subscriber info in the models? what is the creator and what is the booster and how is it connected to the Post model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here are the basics minus the subscribers because I don't see the relation clearly. This is how to parse the name and the number of posts. \

```
my_list = []

for sub in subs:
    name = sub.creator.name
    auth_id = sub.creator.id
    posts = Post.objects.filter(author=auth_id)
    num_of_posts = len(posts)
    my_list.append({
        'name':name,
        'post_count': num_of_posts,
    })
```

then you would pass mylist thru the template context.

Comment: Thanks, its working for me. for subscriber count I used the below code

subscribers = subscription.objects.filter(creator = auth_id)
num_of_subcribers = len(subscribers)

Answer (score 0):

It is a common mistake to name the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) to the same value as the name of the field. The `related_name` parameter however is the name of the *reverse* relation Django will automatically add. So here it means a relation to access for example the related `subscription` objects of a given `CustomUser`.

Therefore it makes more sense to rename these, for example like:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='created_subscriptions'
    )
    booster = models.ForeignKey(
        CustomUser,
        default=None,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='boosted_subscriptions'
    )
    sub_value = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    sub_id = models.TextField(blank =True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dateSubscribed = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    dateSubscriptionEnded = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    paymentCount = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

Next we can make a query where:

```
from django.db.models import Count

CustomUser.objects.filter(
    created_subscriptions__booster=request.user
).annotate(
    number_of_posts=Count('post', distinct=True)
)
```

This is a `QuerySet` of `CustomUser`s where each `CustomUser` that arises from this `QuerySet` has an extra attribute `.number_of_posts` that contains the number of posts. You thus can iterate over the queryset directly in the template.